# Is it proper use case for Observable in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I`m new into reactive JS. Can someone say me is it good case to use Observable here?

I need to make console log with data every time between 15 minutes and 20 minutes. How can I use Observable to make this work? Maybe some examples?

I think I need some dataWatcher and intervals where I subscribe to dataWatcher. Is it correct?

```
dataWatcher:Observable<any>
```

Comment: *every time between 15 minutes and 20 minutes* what does that mean? Concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

When your component initializes, start logging every 20 minutes:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  loggerSubscription:Subscription;

  // start logging once the component has initialized
  ngOnInit(){
    this.loggerSubscription =  Observable.interval(1000 * 60 * 20).subscribe(() => {
        console.log(...);
    });
  }
  // when the component is destroyed, unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.loggerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: As @ehrencrona mentioned, you can achieve this with `setInterval` as well

Answer (score 1):

While it's certainly possible to achieve this with observables, I don't see any benefit to doing over just using `setInterval`. Observables are helpful to coordinate more complex asynchronous behavior, typically involving values being fetched/calculated, but in this case the behavior is trivial and does not involve calculating any values.

Comment: worth mentioning that this code will continue to run indefinitely even after the logging component is removed from the view. Might be a good idea to cancel the interval when the logging is no longer needed.